# I can't select multiple objects using Shift-Left Click in object mode

Tags: objects

I cannot see the orange origin point in Blender and cannot select multiple objects using (Shift-Left Click) in object mode. Could someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong, Thanks.
[image]

As you can see the orange origin point is not visible even though I have the object selected in object mode.

Comment: To see the origin  go to the overlays section enable the visibility for origins.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the objects are selectable. For instance, I've turned the Central Empty non-selectable in the following screen capture:

[image]